# Should europe tag be synonyms with eu?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, retagging

Currently there are two tags that have the same function, however they are not set as synonyms:

[europe](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) 
[eu](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu)

Should we re-tag the [eu](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu) questions (only 5 questions) with the [europe](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) tag (81 questions). Or should someone with a higher reputation than myself, set these tags as synonyms to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see the following:

- Significant parts of Europe, such as Norway and Switzerland, are not part of the EU
- Europe is likely to remain coherent for a long time, whereas it is possible that near-future political events might significantly change the definition of the EU.
- All of the questions that I see tagged with EU appear to be fine to tag with Europe.

I would thus recommend re-tagging, and not creating a synonym.

Comment: I think it is odd to lump questions about EU specific funding into a general Europe tag.

Comment: If I follow, it sounds like you are suggesting that [tag:eu] questions are a subset of the [tag:europe] category, and that the broader tag ([tag:europe]) is a good enough classification and the [tag:eu] sub-classification is not necessary. Is that accurate? If so, why *not* create a synonym? That's what we usually do for "subclasses" for which we don't want to maintain a separate tag, because otherwise the separate tag will probably just be recreated soon.

Comment: @ff524 If that's the usual treatment for sub-classes, then it seems reasonable to do here as well.

Comment: I strongly disagree with the third point. The five questions currently tagged [tag:eu] are pretty sterling examples of why the tags are different. Four of them are about EU-specific funding streams, so they do not make sense for non-EU countries, and in [this one](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/45675/) the OP could well be motivated by e.g. EU freedom of movement laws to look specifically in EU countries (admittedly it's a bit vague, but the OP does specifically ask about the EU).

Answer (score 4):

The EU and Europe are not the same. The tag usage, in my opinion, is pretty good and demonstrates a need for two separate tags (and possibly a third tag).

There are questions which apply only to the EU. All the questions currently tagged EU seem correctly tagged. There are few EU specific questions tagged Europe.

There are questions that apply to all of Europe. This seems to be the vast majority of the questions tagged Europe.

There are a few questions that apply to non-EU countries in Europe.

I propose three tags: [europe](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe), [europe-eu](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe-eu), and [europe-non-eu](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe-non-eu) (I don't really like that name/hyphenation). Then we could make [eu](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu) a synonym of [europe-eu](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe-eu).

Comment: "europe-non-eu" defines a set of countries that have very little in common. I don't think that is a particularly useful tag.

Answer (score 3):

The current situation is fine. [eu](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eu) is specific to grants and administrative aspects relating to the political entity of the European Union, and [europe](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe), although a very vague tag since academia varies vastly between European countries, describes the geographic entity. [europe](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/europe) can be used to exclude the American or Asian context. They are not synonyms

Answer (score -1):

I am for creating a synonym, for the reasons already perfectly stated in @ff524's comment:

> you are suggesting that eu questions are a subset of the europe category, and that the broader tag (europe) is a good enough classification and the eu sub-classification is not necessary. Is that accurate? If so, why not create a synonym? That's what we usually do for "subclasses" for which we don't want to maintain a separate tag, because otherwise the separate tag will probably just be recreated soon.

I realize that EU does not coincide with Europe. Still, keeping track of the full hierarchy between the various European supernational entities is [quite complicated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1q8sa.jpg), and in my opinion the advantages do not offset the inconvenience of having multiple tags, especially if they are used only for five questions or so.